# Prevent Edge browser to prompt for Save as dialog for Downloading

Tags: javascript

Edge/Internet Explorer always prompts a saveAs Dialog when we run the file download code in our application .

But chrome just downloads the file in the default download folder.

is it possible to achieve the same behavior in Edge/IE. i.e they just download the file in default folder and dont give a saveAs dialog

Doing this in js   (the url is the path of my file)

```
var link = $doc.createElement("a");
    link.download = "document";
    link.href = url;
    $doc.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    $doc.body.removeChild(link);
    delete link;
```

Comment: Please show your code to show how you are invoking the browser to launch.  [mcve] please.

Comment: You should probably remove the `java` tag.

Answer (score 0):

For edge, head to settings, find "Downloads" section, then switch off "Ask me what to do with each download"

[image: Edge download settings]